# How to use ReactJS in hybrid scenarios

Tags: reactjs, yii2

I have an existing MVC project built with Yii2 (a PHP framework) which generates and serves HTML pages.

I'd like to write just one complex Component (with 3rd-party modules and a lot of other dependencies) only for a page (generated by Yii2); so it's important to clarify that I don't want to leave all the frontend side to ReactJS and I don't want / can't migrate to a complete frontend app managed by ReactJS.

What's the best way to integrate ReactJS (with its stuff like npm, Webpack, etc)?

Should I write the ReactJS app in a "npm environment", bundle everything and include the "build" static resources into the Yii2-generated page?

Answer (score 0):

For complex scenarios it is better to use "npm stack" to build your assets and create asset bundle to only register files generated by tools like webpack or gulp. Yii tools for compiling and compressing assets works fine for simple cases, but they're very limited when you compare it to tools from npm ecosystem.

You could look how [official website](https://www.yiiframework.com/) of Yii Framework [was build](https://github.com/yiisoft-contrib/yiiframework.com): they used [yarn](https://github.com/yiisoft-contrib/yiiframework.com/blob/master/package.json) and [gulp](https://github.com/yiisoft-contrib/yiiframework.com/blob/master/gulpfile.js) to build frontend assets and one [simple bundle](https://github.com/yiisoft-contrib/yiiframework.com/blob/master/assets/AppAsset.php) to register generated files. The main difference from normal "npm fronted flow" is that they used [assets-packagist](https://asset-packagist.org) to install frontend dependencies.